# Symbolic link to directory vs. "mount --bind" and rights

Tags: bash, alias, mount

I have a webserver where I run two duplicite versions like this

```
 /home/domains/domainone.com/webroot
 /home/domains/domaintwo.com/webroot
```

Now, I want to share a directory and to be able to write to both of them.

```
 /home/images/
 -> /home/domains/domainone.com/webroot/images/
 -> /home/domains/domaintwo.com/webroot/images/
```

I can manage to do that with "mount --bind", but I always have to make sure, that the directory is mounted. When I use ln -s, I am not able to write to those directories from my PHP script in Apache, even though I set the rights to 777. As I say, with mount --bind, it works correctly, but I would prefer to use symbolic links.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like PHP script can't go though one of the parent directories. Usually Apache is running under "www" or "httpd" user. Make sure that this user/group has rx permissions on `/home/domains`, `/home/domains/domainone.com` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FollowSymLinks was already set, the problem was in fact in 'open_basedir' restriction, where the linked directory was not in the list.

Answer (score 1):

[Try FollowSymLinks as described here](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=28676)

Comment: `FollowSymLinks` is httpd option -- AFAIK nothing to do with PHP.